# What does the "box" mean in "don't block the box"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I see other similar signs saying "don't block the intersection", but what does "box" here mean?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The "box" is the intersection.  When viewed from above, most intersections look like a square, or "box".

Comment: [This image](https://c1.staticflickr.com/1/240/516262942_8538125a35_b.jpg) is a more self-explanatory version of the sign in question. Surprised to see colloquialism on a street sign in either case, personally.

Comment: @txteclipse, would you be equally surprised to find it in the title of a statute? https://www.cga.ct.gov/2009/ACT/PA/2009PA-00171-R00SB-00966-PA.htm

Comment: @user662852 Wild. Equally confusing is the "Fine +2 Points." I guess people from Connecticut must know what it means, but how would they enforce against nonresidents? "I'm sorry, but you can't jargon in the hooplah, that's a three point fine." "Oh, sorry, I didn't know." "Nice try buddy, we get that all the time."

Comment: @user662852 Likely these "points" are "points on your driver's license".  Each time a particular driver is issued a traffic citation, a certain number of points accrue to his or her driver's license.  These points are taken into account when deciding how much your auto insurance company charges you in premiums.  In time, they expire, but if you accrue enough points at one time, your license will be suspended.

Comment: Here is a photo of a roughly rectangular box painted on the road. http://www.ennisflint.com/getattachment/6ae56f82-1526-4db1-a71f-b51c6e7d6a08/3-PreMark